# What is the background song on Naruto Shippuden episode 333 at around 18:30?

Tags: naruto, music

In *Naruto Shippuden* episode 333 at around 18:30, there's a background song playing.

What is the title of that song?

Answer (score 1):

Song's name is Sen'ya (Many nights). It is from Naruto Shippuuden: OST II.